# Why does using @microsoft/sp-dialog inside a SPFX ListViewCommandSet prevent the extension from loading?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extension

I'm trying to do something I've done before. I want to create a new SPFX ListViewCommandSet button which opens a dialog box. However, the moment I reference my custom dialog, the entire extension fails to load with the following error showing up in the console:

```
listview-host-assembly_en-us_22624d1282d23d4584d53bb10af184fb.js:68 Could not load hello-world-command-set in require. Trying in system.js. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at listview-host-assembly_en-us_22624d1282d23d4584d53bb10af184fb.js:68:360145
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.loadComponent (listview-host-assembly_en-us_22624d1282d23d4584d53bb10af184fb.js:68:360113)
    at listview-host-assembly_en-us_22624d1282d23d4584d53bb10af184fb.js:68:361874
    at async Promise.all (/sites/TS20001/Shared%20Documents/Forms/index 1)
```

I'm using node v16.19.0. I've tried following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/guidance/using-custom-dialogs-with-spfx) in a brand new solution.

However when I run `gulp serve --nobrowser` and go to https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/mylist/Forms/AllItems.aspx?debug=true&noredir=true&debugManifestsFile=https://localhost:4321/temp/manifests.js I get the above error and the custom button does not appear.

I've tried using the tutorial's suggested package `office-ui-fabric-react` and also `@fluentui/react` as [suggested here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.16).

Edit: On further experimentation, it seems the moment I do anything with 'ReactDOM', the extension becomes unloadable. E.g. if I comment out the `ReactDOM.render(<ColorPickerDialogContent ... />)` call, the extension loads. If I leave it in, or even if I put something like `alert(ReactDOM)`, the extension refuses to load with the error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out you have to specify the exact version or react.

```
npm i react@17.0.1 react-dom@17.0.1 @types/react@17.0.45 @types/react-dom@17.0.17 --save-exact
```